# How to improve sound isolation of an interior door?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

Interior doors of the type frequently used in rented housing (I'm speaking in particular of apartments) seem to be hollow and do not do a very good job of sound insulation. If for example a laundry room was behind the doors a great deal of the sound from the laundry room would be transmitted to the rest of the apartment.

In which ways could one (price-efficiently) insulate these doors, such that sound transmissions would lessened?

Answer (score 1):

A sound blanket on the laundy side would be simple.  [See my answer here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25893/how-to-reduce-noise-from-my-refrigerator/25904#25904)

Drilling and foaming the door with low expansion, door and window polyurethane foam.  The trick will be figuring out where the cardboard internal baffles go.  I would fill a horizontal row of 3 holes equally spaced, every foot.  Allow some time between fillings to let foam setup. (but not so long for the nozzle to clog (10 min?)

[image]

Comment: A hollow core door usually has a [honeycomb cardboard fill](http://www.instructables.com/files/deriv/FXW/NKZ1/FZNHP0YZ/FXWNKZ1FZNHP0YZ.LARGE.jpg), good luck filling it with foam.  Not to mention the fact that if you over fill the door, the foam will expand and destroy the door.